# Compact convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am trying to show that

$$f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{z+k}$$

converges compactly over $\mathbb{C}$ and starting to think that this statement is false after several attempts.

If I take an $\epsilon >0$ and try to an $N$ so that for $n\geq N$,

$$|| \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{z+k} - f(z)|| < \epsilon,$$

I get stuck. The $z+k$ is preventing me from putting a bound on the function in a way that is useful. I've tried using the Weierstrass M-test, but I couldn't make it work either.

Comment: "Converges compactly over $\;\Bbb C\;$" = converges on compact subsets of $\;\Bbb C\;$ ?

Comment: The series is not absolutely convergent, hence you can't use the Weierstraß $M$-test. I'm not yet sure, but it's quite possible that the alternating signs ensure compact convergence nevertheless.

Comment: I don't know what BbbC means, but Converges compactly over $\mathbb{C}$ means for each compact set $G$, there is an index N such that $n\geq N$ implies the poles of $f_{n}$ do not lie in $G$ and the series $\sum_{n\geq N}f_{n}$ converges uniformly

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{z+k}=\frac\pi{\sin\pi z}$

Comment: Is there a way for me to massage that series into a solution? Is that a hint to try to write the series in terms of the gamma function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You can write the series as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{z+2k}-\frac1{z+2k-1}=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(z+2k)(z+2k-1)}
$$
which does converge absolutely.

Comment: Would this approach work? Using your hint, write the denominator in powers of (z+2k-1) and then put a bound on (z+2k-1) to use the Weierstrass M test on a convergent p-series?

Comment: @JessicaK: yes, you can also use the fact that the terms are less than $\frac1{(2k-|z|-1)^2}$ when $k$ is big.